# Problema al guardar una lista doblemente ligada en archivo binario

Tags: c++, winapi, binary-files

Estoy haciendo un programa en c++ y winapi donde tengo que ingresar datos de personas, vacunas y usuarios para después guardarlos en listas doblemente ligadas separadas y guardar dichas listas en archivos binarios. Al guardar las listas de vacunas y usuarios en archivos binarios, se generan los archivos y puedo usarlos sin problemas.

El detalle es que al intentar guardar la lista de personas me dice que si se creó, pero al final no se crea, utilice puntos de interrupción y si se ejecuta todo el código.
Aparte, como se puede ver en el código, tengo una condición por si me da error al crear el archivo, pero en ningún momento entra ahí.

Algo que descubrí es que es que, si la lista de personas está vacía si me crea el archivo, pero si tiene algún nodo creado no me genera el archivo. Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano : )

```
struct PERSONAS {

    SYSTEMTIME fecha{}; //Fecha de nacimiento
    int estado_civil{};
    int sexo{};
    int perfil_riesgo{};
    wchar_t nombre[60]{};
    wchar_t apellidopat[30]{};
    wchar_t apellidomat[30]{};
    wchar_t CURP[25];
    wchar_t RFC[30]{};
    wchar_t calle[60];
    wchar_t colonia[30]{};
    wchar_t ciudad[30];
    wchar_t estado[30];
    wchar_t grupo_ocupa[60];
    wchar_t tel[20]{};
    wchar_t foto[200]{};  //Foto en formato BMP
    wchar_t documentoID[200]{};  //Foto en formato BMP
    PERSONAS* sigu{};
    PERSONAS* ante{};

};

void guardarImagenBMP(const wstring& rutaImagen, ofstream& archivo) {
    ifstream imagenBMP(rutaImagen, std::ios::binary);

    if (!imagenBMP) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"No se pudo abrir el archivo de imagen BMP.", L"ALERTA", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    }
    else {
        archivo << imagenBMP.rdbuf(); // Guardar los datos binarios de la imagen en el archivo

        imagenBMP.close();
    }
}

void archivoPersonasSave() {
    ofstream archivoB1;
    archivoB1.open("Personas.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);

    if (archivoB1.fail()) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"No se pudo crear el archivo Personas.", L"ALERTA", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    }
    else {
        int n = 0;
        PERSONAS* auxiliar = Pinicio;
        while (auxiliar != NULL) {
            n++;
            auxiliar = auxiliar->sigu;
        }
        archivoB1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&n), sizeof(n));
        auxiliar = Pinicio;
        while (auxiliar != NULL) {
            archivoB1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&auxiliar->fecha), sizeof(auxiliar->fecha));
            archivoB1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&auxiliar->estado_civil), sizeof(auxiliar->estado_civil));
            archivoB1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&auxiliar->sexo), sizeof(auxiliar->sexo));
            archivoB1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&auxiliar->perfil_riesgo), sizeof(auxiliar->perfil_riesgo));
            archivoB1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&auxiliar->nombre), sizeof(auxiliar->nombre));
            archivoB1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&auxiliar->apellidopat), sizeof(auxiliar->apellidopat));
            archivoB1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&auxiliar->apellidomat), sizeof(auxiliar->apellidomat));
            archivoB1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&auxiliar->CURP), sizeof(auxiliar->CURP));
            archivoB1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&auxiliar->RFC), sizeof(auxiliar->RFC));
            archivoB1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&auxiliar->calle), sizeof(auxiliar->calle));
            archivoB1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&auxiliar->colonia), sizeof(auxiliar->colonia));
            archivoB1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&auxiliar->ciudad), sizeof(auxiliar->ciudad));
            archivoB1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&auxiliar->estado), sizeof(auxiliar->estado));
            archivoB1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&auxiliar->grupo_ocupa), sizeof(auxiliar->grupo_ocupa));
            archivoB1.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&auxiliar->tel), sizeof(auxiliar->tel));
            guardarImagenBMP(auxiliar->foto, archivoB1);
            guardarImagenBMP(auxiliar->documentoID, archivoB1);
            auxiliar = auxiliar->sigu;
        }
        archivoB1.close();
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Se ha creado el archivo Personas con exito.", L"ALERTA", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo estás usando ese código? Incluye la función `main` o donde sea que estés llamando la función para guardar la lista.